# Netty list of environment options?

Tags: netty

is there a list of available Netty environment options, starting with -Dio.netty.? I have not found anything at the Netty documentation page or elsewhere.

Comment: Issue raised at https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/6305 as @norman-maurer suggested.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not... Please open an issue I think it would be useful to provide something for this.

Comment: I'll raise an issue but it might get hard for the guys to fix it. I've seen io.netty.util.internal.SystemPropertyUtil.getXX(key) all around the code which sometimes uses static strings and sometimes uses inplace stings for the key...